# NameError: name 'plot_backend' is not defined al intentar graficar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

He estado trabajando con python, pandas y con matplotlib.pyplot para graficar. Constantemente me ha saltado el mismo error:

```
"plot_backend.__name__, self._parent, args, kwargs
NameError: name 'plot_backend' is not defined".
```

No sé por qué sucede; ya intenté muchas cosas diferentes y no funciona. Aunque pruebe con diferentes tipos de gráficas, me sale el error.
Este es todo mi código y no sé cuál es la variable que no definí. ¿Podrían indicarme si me hace falta añadir alguna variable? Recientemente me escribieron que faltaba definir algo, pero aún sigo sin entender.

```
import turtle
from colorama import Fore
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


print('******Control de vacunación******')


fase1a = []
fase1b = []
fase1c = []
fase1d = []
fase1e = []
fase1f = []
fase2a = []
fase2b = []
fase3a = []
fase3b = []
fase3c = []
fase3d = []
fase4a = []
fase4b = []

dpi = []
edad = []  



print (Fore.GREEN + '---------Grupos priorizados para vacunación-----------')
print('\n')
print (Fore.RED + '1. Trabajador de establecimientos de sauld asistencial que atienden pacientes con COVID-19 (primera línea).')
print ('2. Trabajador de establecimiento de salud asistencial no incluidos en sub-fase 1a y comunitario de apoyo.')
print ('3. Estudiantes de ciencias de salud que realizan prácticas asistenciales en establecimientos de salud.')
print ('4. Cuerpos de Socorro')
print ('5. Personas internadas en hogares o instituciones de adultos mayores (asilos)')
print ('6. Trabajadores del sector de salud (administrativos).')

print (Fore.YELLOW + '7. Adultos mayores de 70 y más años; adultos con una o más de las siguientes condiciones:hipertensión, diabetes, enfermedad pulmonar, enfermedad renal, enfermedades cardiovasculares y  cerebrovasculares, inmunosupresión u obesidad.')
print ('8. Adultos de 50 a 69 años.')

print (Fore.MAGENTA + '9. Trabajadores del sector de seguridad nacional (PNC, PMT, militares, personal del sistema penitenciario.')
print ('10. Trabajadores de municipalidades y entidades que prestan servicios esenciales (electricidad, agua, recolección de basura).')
print ('11. Trabajadores del sector de educación.')
print ('12. Trabajadores del sector de justicia.')

print (Fore.BLUE + '13. Adultos de 40 a 49 años.')
print ('14. Adultos de 18 a 39 años.')

print (Fore.GREEN + '------------------------')
print (Fore.GREEN + '------------------------')



#-----------------------------------------------------------------

bol = True
while bol:



k = input(Fore.BLACK + '¿Quiere ingresar al programa? (Si,No): ').lower()
if k == 'si':
    
    
    nombre = input('Ingrese su nombre completo:')
    edad1 = int(input('Ingrese su edad:')) 
    edad.append(edad1)
    dpi1 = input('Ingrese su DPI o CUI:')
    dpi.append(dpi1)
    paciente = [nombre, 'DPI o CUI:' + dpi1, str(edad1) + 'años']
    opcion = int(input('Escoja el grupo al que pertenece:'))
    
    
    if opcion == 1:
        print(paciente) 
        print(Fore.RED + 'Será vacunado en la fase 1a.')
        fase1a.append(nombre)
        print('-----------------------------')
        
    if opcion == 2:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.RED + 'Será vacunado en la fase 1b.')
        fase1b.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')

    if opcion == 3:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.RED + 'Será vacunado en la fase 1c.')
        fase1c.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        

    if opcion == 4:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore. RED + 'Será vacunado en la fase 1d.')
        fase1d.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        

    if opcion == 5:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.RED + 'Será vacunado en la fase 1e')
        fase1e.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')

    if opcion == 6:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.RED + 'Será vacunado en la fase 1f')
        fase1f.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        

    if opcion == 7:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.YELLOW + 'Será vacunado en la fase 2a.')
        fase2a.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        

    if opcion == 8:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.YELLOW + 'Será vacunado en la fase 2b.')
        fase2b.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        
    if opcion == 9:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + 'Será vacunado en la fase 3a.')
        fase3a.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        
    if opcion == 10:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + 'Será vacunado en la fase 3b.')
        fase3b.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        
    if opcion == 11:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + 'Será vacunado en la fase 3c.')
        fase3c.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        
    if opcion == 12:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + 'Será vacunado en la fase 3d.')
        fase3d.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        
    if opcion == 13:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.BLUE + 'Será vacunado en la fase 4a.')
        fase4a.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        
    if opcion == 14:
        print(paciente)
        print(Fore.BLUE + 'Será vacunado en la fase 4b.')
        fase4b.append(nombre)
        print(Fore.BLACK + '-----------------------------')
        
    


else:
    
    
    a = {'Edad': edad, 'DPI': dpi, 'Fase 1A': fase1a, 'Fase 1B': fase1b, 'Fase 1C': fase1c, 'Fase 1D': fase1d, 'Fase 1E': fase1e, 'Fase 1F': fase1f,
            'Fase 2A': fase2a, 'Fase2B': fase2b, 'Fase 3A': fase3a, 'Fase 3B': fase3b, 'Fase 3C': fase3c, 'Fase 3D': fase3d,
            'Fase 4A': fase4a, 'Fase 4B': fase4b}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
    df = df.transpose()
    df.to_csv('vacunas.csv')
    print(df)
    
    df.plot(x ='Fase', y='Pacientes', kind = 'bar')
    plt.show() 

    
    bol = False
```

Este es todo el código. Todo funciona, menos la última parte después del else. ¿Qué tengo que hacer para poder graficar?

Comment: No creo que el problema sea al gráficas, podrías poner todo el código?

Comment: Lo que te dice el error es que no existe una variable `plot_backend` verifica que si la tengas y que este bien escrita en todo el código

Comment: Gracias Christian. Ya puse todo el código.

Comment: En que linea aparece el error?

Comment: En la línea 188.

Comment: pero que linea es? @_@

Comment: df.plot(x ='Fase', y='Pacientes', kind = 'bar')
 plt.show()

Comment: El error sale en esas líneas

Comment: Lo siento to, no se a que se debe :(